# Moments of zeta function/L-functions

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I am currently interested in studying the moments of zeta function (or L-function in general) which is the quantity: 
\begin{equation}
I_k(T) = \int_{0}^T|\zeta(1/2+it)|^{2k}dt
\end{equation}
$\textbf{Question:}$ Are there any expository papers/book chapters that are not very technical and at the same time provide some historical perspective, motivation, current status of the problem and such?

So far, I have been only able to find that the problem is still open for $k\geq 3$. As for the historical perspective\motivation, the best sources I have found are the "Introduction" sections of some technical papers related to this topic.

Comment: Iwaniec and Montgomery wrote excellent books about Analytic Number Theory, they are a good starting point. As a free advice, however, I would suggest you to focus on some simpler problem. This is an *extremely* tough nut to crack.